# Convert Latitude and Longitude Values (Degrees) to Double . Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude values which are in degrees to double.
  the values are like this

```
 "latitude":"25°21 N",
        "longitude":"55°23 E"
```

When i try to log this in android it is coming like this.
 [image]

What is this `"A^"` special char there . How it came. Also when i try to save the log 
it was like   `25°21 N`

How to convert the degree values to double for latitude and longitude ?

Thanks

Comment: Some example code of what you're really trying to do would help.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I am just logging the latitude value and getting extra chars in my string when view using ddms logcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for your current example, you have to parse your input, one time it is parsed assign to that formula.

Parsing the input

```
Map<String,String> yourMap; //imagine is your input 
                            //"latitude":"25°21 N",
                            //"longitude":"55°23 E"

String latitude = yourMap.get("latitude");
String hour = latitude.split("º")[0];
String minute = latitude.split("º")[1].split(" ")[0];

// This is a very ugly way to parse it, better do with regular expressions, 
// but I'm not an expert on them and cannot figure them.


//Parse result
String hour = "25";
String minute = "21";
String second = "0";

//Formula
double result = Integer.intValue(hour) + 
                Integer.intValue(minute) / 60 + 
                Integer.intValue(second) / 3600;
```

Comment: yes thanks, before that i have situation to parse the string i am getting .

Comment: I get string like  25°21 N  and when i try to log it is show some special char in between . How it came ?

Comment: updated the answer to show you, an ugly way to parse your string

Comment: it show incorrect characters because you are not using UTF-8 when showing them, String has no encoding, you have to define the encoding when retrieving an array from it, like using getBytes method, String.getBytes("UTF-8")

Comment: If latitude contains 'S' instead of 'N' or if longitude contains 'W' instead of 'E', then result should be multiplied by (-1).